# How to improve download speed of files coming from IPFS?

Tags: video, blockchain, ipfs

I've video files that are showing on my Web Page. The average size of a single file is 20 MB. The source of those video files is coming from IPFS. My IPFS URL looks like this:

https://ipfs.io/ipfs/ + ipfsHash

I've got a decent internet speed i.e. 20Mbps. All other video Websites run really fast. I believe there is nothing wrong with my code since just running the IPFS URL in the browser takes a lot of time. If that's all I can get from IPFS, are there any faster decentralized IPFS alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IPFS is a distributed peer to peer storage and delivery solution - it requires a certain critical mass to achieve some of its benefits and I would guess to achieve good speeds.

In other words the more people viewing, storing and distributing the video or parts of it, the better it will work.

Its also quite likely that the traditional 'http' websites are using mechanisms like adjustable bit rate (ABR) streaming and low latency fragmented streams, mechanisms created and tuned specifically to speed video delivery on HTTP networks.

Comment: My videos are unique, intended to be seen or used by individuals, probably just once. So, I guess, IPFS might not be the best solution for me. Is that right?

Comment: That makes it makes it tricky as you'll also miss out on benefits of a CND etc. If you know who will watch then you could try to preload the video in advance of them actually hitting the play button.